# What is the different between "Make" and "Build" in context menu of project build configuration?

Tags: delphi, build

When I pop up context menu of a Delphi project's build configuration, I see menu items of "Make", "Build" and "Clean".

What is the different between "Make" and "Build"?  It seems that both perform same task.

Comment: Isn't MAKE only for C++ Builder targets, and Build and Clean are available for Delphi?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233671/what-is-the-difference-between-compiling-and-building-in-delphi

Comment: @Warren Your right, it's called Compile in Delphi.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- Build compiles all source files in the project.
- Make compiles those that have changed since the last make or build.

Note that make is actually a little more complex. A unit, let us say unitA, can require re-compilation during a make even if unitA has not changed. This happens when unitA uses another unit, unitB, and the interface section of unitB has changed since the last make or build.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Build_Project) for Build states:

> Rebuilds all files in your current
>   project regardless of whether they
>   have changed. Building is useful when
>   you are unsure which files have
>   changed, or if you have changed
>   project or compiler options.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compile_and_Make_All_Projects) for Make states:

> Compiles only those files that have
>   changed since the last build, as well
>   as any files that depend on them.

Comment: Also. Changes in .INC files are ignored, so if you change conditionals you must also force a build.

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for those?

Comment: @ThomCunningham I've added links to the answer

Answer (score 12):

Make compiles outdated modules (the ones that were changed since the last project compilation), while build (re)compiles all modules.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a related information : what "Clean" do compared to "Build" and "Make". It appears to delete the "pre-compiled header" database.

Comment: You might do better to post this as a new q and post an answer to it yourself.  It probably deserves higher visibility than it will get here.