# Delphi-XE4 iOS uploading new releases somehow ignored

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

I have a very mysterious problem.

I am somehow not uploading my new app versions correctly even if everything it seemingly correct. I determine this by download the "new" versions and seeing nothing has changed.

1)
Before release I test my changes are included and working on device-debug + device-adhoc.

2)
I then build and deploy for app store. Before uploading my .ipa file into "Application Loader" I make sure the **.ipa file has just been generated**. I then select it and the upload/verification process goes find without errros and some days later I get a message new app has been released...

3)
I then uninstall my existing app (just to make sure) and download and install the new app version from appstore - it is still the same. This is driving me nuts. I think I have tried to eliminate potential places where I could have errored, but somehow somewhere something is going terrible wrong for me. This is a fairly recent new problem - never had it in the past.

I am hoping if somehow can think of ways I can diagnose at what steps this is going wrong... I know it must be me that have an error somewhere. I recognize when something looks like a "Doh!" thing, but I believe I have tried a varity of methods to pinpoint it.

I have also tried clear out out scratch/temp directory before building + deploying. However, I am still wondering. Could it be some cache/path setting somewhere that makes Delphi compile incorrect app executable only when doing release builds? (I have of course also long time ago deleted all old directory paths that could contain earlier builds, but still...)

Answer (score 1):

I did not see that you have already tried it on a new buddy phone & it worked. So editing my answer.

Can you try to remove your device ID from the profile settings in developer page & give a try downloading it.

There may be problem in building & compiling with Delphi.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3237580/1307844) is a post that differentiates between the same.

Please do see the accepted answer for that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235625/1307844).

Hope that helps. (I know you are really pissed off waiting for the whole long app approval process & annoyed seeing the same old version.)

Comment: I will take a look at it and get back to you. I am interested in getting the issue resolved eben though the update system appears to work (now I have had two buddies check) - except on my iPhone for whatever weird reason :) I will get back to you when I have tried it. Upvoted the answer for now!

Answer (score 0):

I had a buddy try download the latest app version, and he successfully and ran the new version... So I now must assume it is somehow my iPhone that is strange. I remove all app instances (debug, old appstore download) - then download the new version from app store. After that, my iPhone shows the "new" text on the launch icon, but still launches an old version... somehow

Comment: But if someone can explain why my iPhone does that, i Will throw the bounty that way :)

Comment: Can you try to remove your device ID from the profile settings in developer page & give a try downloading it.