# How to have, Delphi source code visible during remote debugging with Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, debugging

I'm starting with the Delphi 2010 remote debugger. There is some good information [here](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Remote_Debugger) and I can start and execute my program on the remote machine. I can't get Delphi to step through my source code though, despite the fact that when run locally, all works fine. All I get is the CPU view and any breakpoints I set get shown disabled when I start the program. My target machine has my exe file together with rsm and map files just built.

My source paths are declared relative to the project i.e

....\Source\MyFiles

but this should stand whilst debugging should it not?

Comment: This is fixed in Update 4 for Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found this web site very useful. http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Remote_Debugger

The first section "Using the Remote Debugger with Delphi 2010" contains a link to an updated version of the remotedbg140 application that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the .rsm file to the target too ?

The relative paths should be ok if it compiles (then the working dir is ok), at least it is working for me with D2009.

(about working dir: see [Delphi debug a wrong unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603077/delphi-debug-a-wrong-unit/2603410#2603410) )

Comment: Yes, as I said above, *.exe, *.map and *.rsm are all in the target folder.